# How to pass value from C# variable to Slider Maximum (XAML) any number of times?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, slider

I beg you, please help who knows. I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks. It is necessary to transfer the value from the variable to the Slider Maximum when the button is clicked and make it so that it can change. That is: the first time I pressed the button - the maximum value of the slider went to 10, the second time I pressed the button - the value of the slider maximum changed to another and so at least as many times. I managed (it was not difficult at all, I'm sure every beginner can even cope with this) to make a transfer from the button, but I don't understand what needs to be done to somehow "bind" this variable in the slider maximum.

```
class Perv
{
    public static double d; //change it
    public static void Favorite_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        VtorClass.Max = d; //I know that you can change it directly (without resorting to the d variable, I wrote it just to make it clear where the data changes,
        //for example, it can write a for loop with this variable, but it does not change the essence: this variable changes and when the button is pressed, the variable indicating the maximum possible number slider maximum should change.
    }
}

public class VtorClass
{
    public static double Max;
}

public class Tri
{
    //this is the class where (if it should) contain the logic for assigning the slider maximum value
}
```

I also tried the option: Maximum="{x:Static local:VtorClass.Max}", but it has a problem - it works, but it works only once at startup, then if you change that variable - it will change only in the class, and property Maximum to it won't address (does not react).

Solution:

```
 public double Mx = 1;
        public void Dada(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Mx += 1;
            "x:Name yuor Slider".Maximum = Mx;
        }
```

Now another problem: in the main page (from where other pages are launched) (this page has the Shell type for me), it doesn’t work out that way, it’s not even about INotifyPropertyChanged or Binding, but simply that x: Name which is assigned to the Slider is not clogged with generation in the NamePage.xaml.g.cs class. What is interesting: in all other classes (pages), everything is automatically driven in to be called from the c # code of the same page, but not in the main page - Shell.

I tried to manually enter x:Name - it worked, but after compiling and building the project, the program itself deletes this data, and if it remains, then the links that you use in c # - “x:Name of your Slider”. Maximum = Mx; - exactly this “x:Name of your Slider” is null.

And what to do with this null - only good programmers know.

I also tried to transfer Shell to other folders or to another class (as an instance of Shell and as a link to the one created in the main class) - nothing: either other errors, or it is simply created, but without a slider and without color (that is, empty, without elements), or anything else that could be.

If someone reads this and knows the answer or a possibility, or a way, at least something that can solve such a problem - I beg you to help me, I’ve been sitting at this for 16 hours ... almost every day, even crack - I don’t understand.

(Sorry for the whining).

Comment: Are you looking to do true binding with MVVM structure, or are you simply looking to modify your slider max value with the click of a button?

Comment: ```
 public double Mx = 1;
        public void Dada(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Mx += 1;
            "x:Name yuor Slider".Maximum = Mx;
        }
```

You are absolutely right! I express my deep gratitude to you. I improved a little.)